# The cardinality of the group $\mathrm{SL}(k,\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, modules, linear-groups

I want to calculate the cardinality of the group $\mathrm{SL}(k,\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})$, $k,n \in \mathbb{N}$. When $n$ is prime, it is easy to calculate, so I want to know the general case.

Comment: I assume that you mean the *cardinality*, also known as the *order* of the group, and I have edited your question to say this. But perhaps you meant the *exponent* of the group, or something else? If so please explain.

Comment: @ZevChonoles Thanks for editing, it is cardinality exactly.

Comment: Hint: Consider $\mathrm{GL}$ first. Look first at the case that $n$ is a prime power. Remember that a matrix is invertible iff its determinant is invertible, and an element in $\mathbb{Z}/p^e$ is invertible iff its redution to $\mathbb{Z}/p$ is invertible. Do the general case by a short exact sequence and the Chinese Remainder Theorem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Step 1.** For a commutative ring $R$, we have $\mathrm{GL}_{n}(R) / \mathrm{SL}_{n}(R) \cong R^{*}$.

**Step 2.** $|\mathrm{GL}_{n}(\mathbb{F}_{q})| = (q^{n}-1)(q^{n}-q)\cdots (q^{n}-q^{n-1})$.

**Step 3.** Let $R$ be a commutative local ring with maximal ideal $\mathfrak{m}$ and residue field $K = R / \mathfrak{m}$ . Then $|\mathrm{GL}_{n}(R)| = |\mathfrak{m}|^{n^{2}} |\mathrm{GL}_{n}(K)|$

**Step 4.** For a commutative rings $R$, $S$, we have $\mathrm{GL}_{n}(R \times S) \cong \mathrm{GL}_{n}(R) \times \mathrm{GL}_{n}(S)$.

Now, we can calculate the order of $\mathrm{GL}_{k}(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})$. First, if $n = p^{k}$, $\mathbb{Z}/p^{k-1}\mathbb{Z}$ is the unique maximal ideal of $\mathbb{Z}/p^{k}\mathbb{Z}$ with residue field $\mathbb{F}_{p}$. Hence, applying 3. and 2., we get $|\mathrm{GL}_{k}(\mathbb{Z}/p^{k}\mathbb{Z})|$.
Combining this with 4., we get the general order for $n = p_{1}^{k_{1}}\cdots  p_{r}^{k_{r}}$. Since $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z} \cong \mathbb{Z}/ p_{1}^{k_{1}}\mathbb{Z}\times \cdots \times \mathbb{Z}/p_{r}^{k_{r}}\mathbb{Z}$ , we have $|\mathrm{GL}_{k}(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})| = |\mathrm{GL}_{k}(\mathbb{Z}/p_{1}^{k_{1}}\mathbb{Z})| \cdots  |\mathrm{GL}_{k}(\mathbb{Z}/p_{r}^{k_{r}}\mathbb{Z})|$.

Finally, step 1. implies $|\mathrm{SL}_{k}(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})| = |\mathrm{GL}_{k}(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})|/\phi(n)$.